# Rendering HAML using javascript in partial in ERB, Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I have started working on a project and the person before me used HAML to display two select boxes and update the second based on the selection of the first. I do not understand how to convert the HAML to ERB so I just put the HAML in a partial. The first select box displays the correct values but the second does not contain anything. How can I make the first box update the second with the correct value? The first one contains states, then the second is supposed to contain installations base on the state selected. Here is my code:

Search view:

```
<%= render 'state_installation_select' %>
```

HAML partial:

```
= state_installation_select @states, @installation_options_by_state # ProgramsHelper
```

ProgramsHelper:

```
def state_installation_select(states, installation_options_by_state)
    haml_tag(:div, class: 'field') do
      haml_concat(label_tag :state, "Please select your state")
      haml_concat(select_tag :state, options_for_select(states), include_blank: true, class: 'state state_installation_select')
    end

    haml_tag(:div, class: 'field') do
      haml_concat(label_tag :installation_id, "Please select your installation")
      haml_concat(select_tag :installation_id, nil, include_blank: true, class: 'installation state_installation_select')
    end
    content_for :domready, %(InstallationSelect.init(#{installation_options_by_state.to_json});).html_safe
  end
```

Program Controller:

```
def search_form_for_parents
    @installations = Installation.all
    @states = Installation.states
    @installations_by_state = @installations.group_by(&:state_code)
    @installation_options_by_state = @installations_by_state.each_with_object({}){ |(state,installations), h| h[state] = installations.map{|i| [i.name, i.id]} }
end
```

Program Javascript:

```javascript
var InstallationSelect = {
  init: function(installations_for_state){

    $state_select = $('select.state.state_installation_select');

    $state_select.change(function(){
      var state = $(this).val();
      var installations = installations_for_state[state] || [];
      var $installation_select = $(this).parent().parent().find('select.installation.state_installation_select');

      $installation_select.html( InstallationSelect.options_for_select(installations) );
    }).triggerHandler('change');
  },

  options_for_select:function(container){
    var options = jQuery.map(container, function(c){
      return '<option value="' + c[1] + '">' + c[0] + '</option>';
    });

    return options;
  }

};
```

Comment: Err.... just wrap your `= ...` in `<%= ... %>` and your HAML becomes ERB. It's pretty simple.

Comment: I get undefined method `haml_tag' for #<#<Class:0x007f906df79b08>:0x007f906dc50d78>                             The partial renders but the javascript doesn't work

Comment: you also need to rename your file `.html.haml` to `.html.erb` otherwise Rails will keep trying to find haml code

Comment: You shouldn't have `haml_tag` inside your `state_installation_select` since now you are using an ERB engine to render the view, which does not define an `haml_tag` method nor include the Haml helper module which such method is defined in.